# Speed up LINQ Object Query

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to speed up the following LINQ Object query:

```
var setOfCodes = codeList1
    .SelectMany(q => q.Codes)
    .Union(codeList2.SelectMany(q => q.Codes)
    .Union(codeList3.SelectMany(q => q.Codes)
    .ToList();
```

Where

```
codeListX is a List<Item>
```

and

```
public Item {
    public List<int> Codes = new List<int>();
}
```

Example:

```
var codeList1 = new List<Item> {
    new Item {
        Codes = new List<int> {
            100,
            105,
            110
        }
    },
    new Item {
        Codes = new List<int> {
            100,
            110,
            115
        }
    },
};
var codeList2 = new List<Item> {
    new Item {
        Codes = new List<int> {
            150,
            155,
            160
        }
    },
    new Item {
        Codes = new List<int> {
            150,
            155,
            170
        }
    },
};
```

And the output should be (Not fussed about order, I can sort later):

```
100, 105, 110, 115, 150, 155, 160, 170
```

IE: Outputs a list containing all the codes that appear within the `codeListX`'s.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Two points...one, it would be really nice if you'd at least post compilable code when asking a question.  It's much more considerate.  Second, what makes you think it's slow?  Have you profiled it?  What would qualify as fast instead?

Comment: @DavidL sorry, the code here is a simplified version of what I am actually using. As for why it is slow, these `codeListsX`'s, when flattened, contain ~10-100 Codes per day in a date range. As the date range increases, the time for this code to return massively increases. I was looking into speeding this up. For reference, about 500 codes takes 1 second on my dev system to result in a unique list.

Comment: Simplified is fine.  Uncompilable is not :).  The real culprit here is the union.  Avoiding it altogether, as in Xiaoy's answer below is vastly more efficient since you no longer need to produce a product of an ever increasing number of sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it like this :

```
var setOfCodes = new[] { codeList1, codeList2, codeList3 }
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Codes)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Damn, didn't realise this would be so much faster. For reference, my method was giving me 1200ms for this, whereas this method was giving me 100ms.